# How to make agent as stationary and create new agent and add parameter on it and move it to Remote?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am programming in Jade for the first time. And I want some help regarding  the problem of mobility of agent.

To make agent as stationary mobility by Jade, should I extends jade.core.Agent or another class? and If I want it to move or dispatch parameter of new agent that i have created at local to remote, what should I do? When I dispatch it do I need to know the address or agent of remote host or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like stationary or remote agent . Any agent you write will extend the  jade.core.Agent class  . Every agent you write is capable of moving to a remote host via two ways :

1. calling doMove() method internally in an agent via a cyclic behavior on meeting certain conditions or on receiving a trigger message from other agent .
2. Asking the AMS agent to move your agent using move-agent ontology .

Now coming to the knowing of the destination address . It's generally good practice to create your application as a single distributed platform with remote containers , to move an agent all you need is the remote container name you want to move to  . if you want across platform agent mobility you have to use a JADE addon , its not enabled by default .